# Why is 'very + ungradable adjective' used more often lately?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, intensifying-adverbs

Excellent, wonderful, terrible, superior --- these normally do not come with the intensifier 'very' before them. But the results of the Google Ngram show recent acute pick-ups, such as below:

[image]

What do you think triggered this trend, and is pulling it up?

Comment: The growing opacity of the original meaning to some speakers plus an increasing tendency to use boosters with adjectives could be plausibly seen as triggers.

Comment: The tendency has been more pronounced after the turn of the century than before. Do you feel that in everyday conversation? And it's looking up so steep. Just wonder why it is.

Comment: Yes, I do, but this is definitely a question of register and happens in other languages as well.

Comment: You find 'very' used as an intensifier to add a sensational feel - e.g. [Micky Spillane](https://pulpcovers.com/tag/mickeyspillane/) (writer of pulp novels) was very fond of saying that someone was found to be 'very dead' (e.g. they had a big hole in their head) or a nubile woman was 'very naked'.

Comment: @Michael Harvey. This use of 'very' seems similar to that of 'so,' which has been prevalent for ages. Is the sensational 'very' a recent arrival, particularly one after around 2000? I am curious why the curve is turning up so sharply then. Is it Spillane? Any famous actor/actress? The left end is 2005. Any thing happen in 2003? 2004? 2005?

Comment: Correction: the left end is 2008. And the sharp pick-up starts around 2005. Did anything happen?